# Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach, and $T : X \to Y$ a bounded linear map. When is $T$ closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I know that $||T(x)|| \geq C ||x||$ for some $C$ is equivalent. I am looking for less analytic conditions, maybe something to do with the topological structure of $X$. Does anyone know some?

By $T$ closed I mean that the image of $T$ is closed in $Y$.

Addenum:

My reason for doing this is:

I am trying to argue that the Schwartz class S is not normable by displaying it as a dense subspace of L1, and then trying to argue that (given normability) the inclusion can be upgraded to surjectivity (which is nonsense), by showing that the range is closed. Since I don't know what the norm looks like, I wanted to make use of some less analytical property of S in order to show that the range is closed.

Comment: Do you mean, when is the range of $T$ closed?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I mean that $im T$ is closed, not that the graph of $T$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

No, $\|Tx\| \ge C \|x\|$ is not equivalent.  The range of a bounded linear operator $T: X \to Y$ is closed iff there is $C>0$ such that $\|Tx\| \ge C \|x + \text{ker}(T)\|$, i.e. that the operator $\widetilde{T}: X / \text{ker}(T) \to Y$ given by $\widetilde{T} \circ \pi = T$ is an isomorphism onto its range 
(where $\pi$ is the quotient map of $X$ to $X/\text{ker}(T)$.

It is also a theorem that $T$ has closed range iff its dual $T^*: Y^* \to X^*$
has closed range.

I'm not sure what you're getting at with "topological structure of $X$".  You could say, for example, that if $T$ is injective and $Y$ has no subspaces isomorphic to $X$, then $T$ can't have closed range.

Comment: Thanks, good point. I think in my mind (and at least in the problem I was working on), $T$ was implicitely injective.

Comment: I am trying to argue that the Schwartz class S is not normable by displaying it as a dense subspace of $L^1$, and then trying to argue that (given normability) the inclusion can be upgraded to surjectivity (which is nonsense), by showing that the range is closed. Since I don't know what the norm looks like, I wanted to make use of some less analytical property of $S$ in order to show that the range is closed.